# Access, Read, Write, Close Cloud Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

File #1 - Computer Side - is trying to access File #2 - OneDrive - write in the document on page 1, check page 2 to see if Badge or Shift matches in Column 1, then Return Column 2 value. Then close File #2 and display the returned message from File #2 in File #1.

I've tried the following:

```
sfilename = "link-to-sheet"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename)
```

This raised up a Security Login window, which my Company hasn't given us access too (Thanks IT!) so I can't test this method!

So then I tried the following

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink address:="Link-to-sheet"
```

This opened up the workbook in a new Chrome tab, but I couldn't get any VBA to select the Sheet that is required.

Haven't ever tried to access a workbook on the Cloud before so exploring new waters!

If anyone has any suggestions, or anywhere to look, please let me know!

Edit: File #2 is edited by multiple computers, so I can't open it in Excel to get the data, as it locks the others out!

Comment: It looks to me as though you need to use Microsoft Graph or PowerAutomate to do what you want.  From VBA, you would call an API to retrieve the result you're after.  That API could be done in an Azure Function or via PowerAutomate using OfficeScripts (suggested) to do the comparison logic you spoke about.  VBA and the web version don't talk, it's simply not the same thing.

Comment: Ah Wonderful! Thanks for the reply! I'll go and look down these avenues!

Comment: If you need a hand, let me know, happy to help further.  This may assist.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466547/power-automate-how-to-extract-hyperlink-from-excel-formula

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll give it a shot and if I get stuck, I'll come back to you!

Comment: G'Day mate, cant seem to find out how to activate OfficeScripts in my Excel. Running Office 365 Personal edition. Everything I found online is about Office 365 Business. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, maybe upgrade to a developer subscription. You get a bunch of E5 licenses which gives you pretty much everything you need, but, there are caveats, the first one being that you need to continue to develop otherwise you will lose it. I’ve got one and have never looked back … check it out … https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program